ThinkPad paint or coating on metal scraping off
I've been using my ThinkPad P51 for about six years now, including taking in and out of a backpack many times. It seems like the black paint or coating on the metal chassis has started to flake off, leaving a light yellowish residue. Is it possible to repaint these surfaces black or clean them? Will the lack of paint reduce corrosion and outside material resistance?

My phone doesn't take macro photos but here is a little bit clearer. I tried scratching off the residue and a little bit of black paint came off too. The bare surface looks like gray metal.

I had an idea of trying to scrape off residue to bare metal and using spray paint like Krylon. It won't match the original paint color or smoothness but it'll stick out less.

That does not look like paint that "flaked off", but rather wear or scraping, i.e. abrasion. That cannot be touched-up to look like new, but since your keyboard & touchpad are quite dirty that is probably not the goal. "Will the lack of paint reduce corrosion" - No (but you probably meant to ask the opposite). "... outside material resistance" - "Resistance" to what? What "material"?

Thank you. I said "flaked off" because sometimes the paint would fall of in little flakes. I mean reduce (corrosion and outside material resistance). Outside meaning if a little bit of liquid gets on it, or if it gets further wear.

On second look of your photo, I'm surprised where (e.g. recesses) there is not black paint/coating. I can't tell if that is actually no paint or rather dirt. Suggest you give your laptop a really through cleaning, and then submit another photo that clearly shows the "light yellowish residue". I didn't vote on your post (yet). It's the possible remedies that could be opinion-based. Read the description more carefully.

I tried to get a clearer picture. What does a thorough cleaning entail? I can wipe it down or use an air duster, but the residue will only come off if I scratch it with a fingernail.

Stop scraping off the paint if your goal is to make the paint look less worn. You will really have to decide if it’s worth trying to repaint, which is something, that most people would not attempt to do because of the material

I might try it for fun. I understand the laptop is a bit old now. It was like $1200 from the company's store, and $300 used now.

@DrMoishePippik can you post as an answer? This seems like the easiest route.

@qwr, as requested, it's an answer.

There are appliance touch-up paints in applicator bottles. These are mostly high gloss, but I see some matte black advertised, such as these examples. A small brush makes it easy to apply where needed.
However, painting would be strictly for appearance; the loss of paint does not damage the laptop. Be careful not to drip it into the machine and damage it, even if it's "only" valued at $300.
In order for the paint to adhere, surface preparation is needed -- otherwise, it will flake off far faster than the original. Here are tips for painting large appliances; scale down accordingly. For example, I'd use a finer grit than US CAMI grit 180.

The older ThinkPads probably could be dismantled safely down to the frame. Looking up a service manual is a good idea

@JourneymanGeek I've disassembled it a few years ago down to the frame to replace a faulty charging port. Wasn't too bad but still took some hours with the service manual, which was good. If that happened today I would just get a new laptop.

I will try out the paint and see how it goes

The auto paint I got at Walmart was too black and shiny compared to the surrounding material. But your answer is a simple enough cosmetic measure so I'll accept it.
